# Co-relating the direct algo for $\epsilon-NFA$ to $DFA$ with the chain : $\epsilon-NFA \rightarrow NFA \rightarrow DFA$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, compilers

I was going through the text : *Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools* by *Ullman et. al* where I came across the following algorithm to convert an $\epsilon\text{-NFA}$ to $\text{DFA}$

> ```
> 1. initially, ϵ-closure(s0) is the only state in Dstates and it is unmarked; 
> 2. while there is an unmarked state T in Dstates do begin 
> 3.    mark T; 
> 4.    for each input symbol a do begin 
> 5.       U := ϵ-closure(move(T, a)); 
> 6.       if U is not in Dstates then 
> 7.           add U as an unmarked state to Dstates; 
> 8.       Dtran[T, a]:= U 
> 9.    end 
> 10. end
> ```
>
> where
>
> \begin{array}{*{20}{|c}}
> \hline
>    {{\text{OPERATION}}} & {{\text{DESCRIPTION}}}\\
>    \epsilon-closure(s) & \text{Set of NFA states reachable from NFA states s on $\epsilon$ -}    \\
>    {} & \text{transitions alone.}\\
> \epsilon-closure(T) & \text{Set of NFA states reachable from some NFA state s in T}    \\
>    {} & \text{on $\epsilon -$ transitions alone.}\\
> move(T,a) & \text{Set of NFA states to which there is a transition on input}    \\
>    {} & \text{symbol a from some NFA state s in T.}\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
>
> The authors then say: We construct $Dstates$, the set of states of $D$, and $Dtran$, the transition table for $D$, in the following manner. Each state of $D$ corresponds to a set of $NFA$ states that $N$ could be in after reading some sequence of input symbols including all possible $\epsilon$-transitions before or after symbols are read. ***The start state of $D$ is $\epsilon-closure(s_0)$***. $^\dagger$ States and transitions are added to $D$ using the algorithm above. ***A state of $D$ is an accepting state if it is a set of $NFA$ states containing at least one accepting state of $N$.*** $^{\dagger\dagger}$

---

The authors then apply the above algorithm on the example :
[image: Example]

The application is straight forward as far as the use of the above algorithm is concerned (so not including it here). By till now while solving problems of these types I followed the following strategy (the strategy followed in the text : *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* by *Hopcroft et. al*) :

---

STEP 1: $\epsilon-NFA$ to $NFA$

To do this for each state $t$ in the $NFA$ we first find $\epsilon-closure(t)$ and store it in $E$. Then for each symbol $a$ in $\Sigma$, we find the $move(E,a)$ and store it in $F$ and find $\epsilon-closure(F)$ and place it at the table location $TABLE[t][a]$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
states & a & b \\ \hline
\rightarrow 0 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\} & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
1 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7\} & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
2 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7\} & \phi \\
3 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\} & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
4 & \phi & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
5 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\} & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
6 & \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\} & \{1,2,4,5,6,7\} \\
7 & \{8\} & \phi \\
8 & \phi & \{9\} \\
9 & \phi & \{10\} \\
*10 & \phi & \phi \\
\end{array}$$

In this above table construction, ***the start state of the $\epsilon-NFA$ $0$ is still the start state of the $NFA$ constructed in the table.*** $^\ddagger$

***And aditional final states in the above NFA are all those those states in the $\epsilon-NFA$, which can reach the final state in the $\epsilon-NFA$ using only $\epsilon$ moves.*** $^{\ddagger\ddagger}$

---

STEP 2: Using subset construction we convert the above table for NFA to that a DFA as shown:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
states & a & b \\ \hline
\rightarrow [0] & [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,4,5,6,7] \\
[1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,4,5,6,7,9] \\
[1,2,4,5,6,7] & [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,4,5,6,7] \\
[1,2,4,5,6,7,9] & [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,4,5,6,7,10] \\
*[1,2,4,5,6,7,10] & [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] & [1,2,4,5,6,7] \\
\end{array}$$

The final state in the $DFA$ is all those sets having at least one final state of the NFA from which it is formed.

This DFA which I have obtained happens to equivalent to the DFA obtained as output from the algorithm in the text. [ This could have been minimized but not going into it as the algorithm under discussion does not do so]

---

***I cannot get the intuition how these two algorithms are equivalent.***

***1. In $\ddagger$ we can start with the actual start state of the $\epsilon-NFA$ but in $\dagger$ we are assuming $\epsilon-closure(s_0)$ as the state of the DFA being produced.***

***2. The equivalence between ${\dagger\dagger}$ and ${\ddagger\ddagger}$ ?***

***3. Moreover in the line `3` of the algorithm I intuitively felt that we could have written :***

```
  `U := ϵ-closure(move(ϵ-closure(T), a));`
```

***Just as we are doing in step 1 of my work out.***

---

**PostScript**

I thought of an intuition as to how the algorithm is working. Let us consider the string $abb$ and give it to the $\epsilon- NFA$ then we trace out the steps.

---

Step (i):

[image: First picture]

Though $0$ is the start state, but from $0$ (using $\epsilon$ moves) we can parallelly be at the states $\{0,1,2,4,7\}$

[image: Second Picture]

From the states $\{0,1,2,4,7\}$ where we can be present parallelly on scanning the symbol $a$ we are at states $\{3,8\}$.

Step (ii):

Now if we are at states $\{3,8\}$ parallelly, using $\epsilon$ moves, we can parallelly be in states $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\}$.

[image: third picture]

Now if we scan the symbol $b$ then we shall reach the states : $\{5,9\}$ in parallel.

[image: Fourth Picture]

Now from states $\{5,9\}$ we can reach states $\{1,2,4,5,6,7,9\}$ in parallel using $\epsilon$ productions only.

[image: Fifth Picture]

Finally on scanning the last symbol $b$ we reach states $\{5,10\}$ and using $\epsilon$ production we can be parallelly at the states $\{1,2,4,5,6,7,10\}$. Since we have reached the final state $10$ we say $\text{YES}$.

The way we found the membership of $abb$, I feel is quite related to the
way the algorithm in text produces the output.

> Output from the algorithm
>
> [image: States]
> [image: Table]

My intuitive approach did actually the following:

$$A \xrightarrow{\text{a}} B \xrightarrow{\text{b}} D \xrightarrow{\text{b}} E$$

Comment: The line `U := ϵ-closure(move(T, ϵ-closure(a) ));` does not really make sense, since `a` is an input symbol, and not a state of the automaton. If you meant `ϵ-closure(move(ϵ-closure(T), a));`, it is not necessary, since `T` is already a closure given the algorithm.

Comment: sorry. it was a typo